# Run GitHub Actions on all open PR branch when commits are pushed to base branch

Tags: git, github, push, github-actions, pull-request

I am using GitHub Actions to run certain tasks on the PR branches like version bumping for the application. As part of this, I wanted to trigger the actions to run on all open PRs when a commit is made to the base branch, say `main`. The config I have in my workflow is

```
on:
  push:
    branches: ['main']
  pull_request:
    branches: ['main']
    types: [opened, reopened, synchronize]
```

This triggers when there is a `push` event on the `main` branch but the action runs on the `main` branch itself. I don't want to bump my versions directly on the main branch. The version bump must be done in the PR before it is merged to the `main` branch. The reason behind this is my CI/CD pipeline listens to the `main` branch for changes. If I do a version bump after my PR merge, it will trigger twice.

I had to used `if: "(github.event_name == 'pull_request')"` on my job to skip the action on the `main` branch.

**Question:** How do I trigger the GitHub Actions on all open PRs when there is a change pushed to the base branch?

Comment: don't think that's possible out of the box. what's the purpose of updating tags in all PRs? do you want to make sure all PRs are up to date when merging? If so, you can configure a branch protection rule "Require linear history".

Comment: As I mentioned, the idea is to have version bumps as part of PRs. So when a PR is merged to the `main` branch, it will update version information on the version file which is used by the application. Now that the version has been changed in the `main` branch, it is required to run the action on all PRs to keep them updated as any open PR might be the next one to be merged.